# Rewriting expression using vector notation

Tags: r, matlab

First time user, sorry if this is the wrong forum.

I am looking for a way to express the following in pure linear algebra vector notation, i.e. remove the element-wise operations.
I am hoping that would make deriving the gradient and Hessian easier.

In MATLAB:

```
sum((W'*p - r).^2 .* m)
```

where W is a matrix, p, r and m are vectors.

In R:

```
sum(t(W) %*% p - r)^2 * m)
```

Thanks

Comment: The above is not actually Matlab code.

Comment: Can you add the actual mathematical expression you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Yellows: I think the OP is actually looking for these; given his 'code'.

Comment: @knedlsepp - Now that you say it this definitely may by the OP's intent. Somehow I understood he wanted the MATLAB equivalent of the R code.

Comment: With respect to which variable are you differentiating anway?

Answer (score 0):

The element-wise squaring makes the vector notation a bit more obscure in terms of everyday linear algebra operators.
The [Hadamard product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_%28matrices%29) is the mathematical term for element-wise multiplication and will be denoted as ○.
Using the Hadamard product, we can write the expression as

[image: expression with Hadamard product]

In brackets, we have the element-wise multiplication, and then we left-multiply with *m*'s transpose to take the sum (vector form of the dot-product).

---

We could also use the [trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29) (denoted here are "tr") and [diag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_matrix#Matrix_operations) operations to get an equivalent expression:

[image: expression using trace and diag]

Here, we use diag to create a square matrix, square the square matrix (which is a valid operation), perform a matrix-vector multiplication, diag the resulting vector, and take its trace.  This one looks like code, but I think that's just because code is trying to look like it ;).